# Database not saving upon program exit

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sqlite

I have the following code, which reads all data from a dataGridView, and supposedly saves it into a database.

```
private void datInp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=dBase1.sqlite;Version=3;");
    con.Open();
    SQLiteCommand sqlDatBas = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO table1(column1,column2) VALUES (@c1,@c2)", con);
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.RowCount-1; i++)
    {
        sqlDatBas.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c1", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
        sqlDatBas.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c2", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
        sqlDatBas.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
```

However, whenever I run it, and use the program to display the current state of the database, it shows as if the data got saved, but, if I exit my program and run it again, it just displays the base database, without the newly added data. Is it because I am missing a column? As the table was created with an ID, but it's supposed to autoincrement. Below is how the table was created.

`CREATE TABLE "table1" ("columnID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "column1" VARCHAR, "column2" VARCHAR)`

I always use `ExecuteNonQuery()`, after every passing of the loop so all data gets added to the database. I display the current state of the database in a dataGridView, and it shows the added items, but not when I restart the program. What am I missing?

Comment: Check if your `SQLite` database file is being copied to `bin\Debug` folder when you build/start application. In Solution Explorer, view properties of your database file and check value of `Copy to Output directory` option

Comment: The current database file is more than a week old; the property is `Copy always` and the build action is `Content`.
However, both the `bin` and `obj` folders appear to be sort of greyed out in the solution explorer. I do not know how to describe it, but the folders itself look like the semi-invisible blocks from Mario (transparent with white dots around them).

Comment: well, that is your problem. When you start your app, an empty database gets copied over the one where you saved your data. Change `Copy to Output directory` option to `Copy if newer`. That means that database will be copied only if it's never than the one in bin\Debug folder (bin\Debug is the place where compiled exe and dll-s  are located).

Comment: Huh, that worked, thank you, mind posting this as an answer and explain a bit more in detail why that is so? The database is not empty upon first start of the program.

Also, if you happen to know why the folders are greyed out, that would help too, thanks.

Comment: folders are grayed out because they don't belong to project. They are created by compiler. `Bin` contains final version of your application (exe, all the needed libraries, configuration, database file etc. Content of that folder can be copied to another computer. btw, no need to make an answer for your question, I'm glad I helped you through comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you included your database file in the project, make sure it is not copied to the output directory each time you build the solution. If you do, the version of the database stored in the project source files, which is not modified by your binary file during execution,  will overwrite the version of the database in your Output directory.

To change this, select your database file in Solution explorer and under `Properties -> Copy to output directory` tell VS  `Do not copy / Copy if newer`.

The second option is useful if you make manual changes to the database and want VS to overwrite any older databases in the Output folder for you. However, I ended up telling VS to never copy it, I prefer to control the copying myself.

Comment: Well, this duplicates what Nino says :)